# Merge / Concatenate Video Files in a Lossless Manner (No Encoding / Compression)

Tags: ffmpeg, lossless

I have few video files I'd like to merge.

I'd like to create a single video of them without any compression, just one after another.

How can it be done using `FFMPEG`?

For the answer we may assume the files are named:

```
Video001.mp4
Video002.mp4
Video003.mp4
.
.
.
Video030.mp4
```

If there a way to automate (Something like `Video*.mp4`) it would be great.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a file named `FileList.txt` with the content:

```
file full/path/to/Video001.mp4
file full/path/to/Video002.mp4
file full/path/to/Video003.mp4
.
.
.
file full/path/to/Video030.mp4
```

One could use the full path instead
2. Run `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i FileList.txt -c copy MergedFile.mp4`.
3. In case of the error `Could not find tag for codec pcm_alaw in stream #1` or something related to PCM audio, know that `FFMPEG` can't generate an `MP4` file with `PCM` audio. Hence chose another container: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i FileList.txt -c copy MergedFile.mkv` or encode the audio: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i FileList.txt -c:v copy -c:a aac MergedFile.mkv`.

**Remark**
The answer is based on:

- [StackOverflow - How to Concatenate Two MP4 Files Using `FFMPEG`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232).
- [Handling PCM Stream in MP4 File in `FFMPEG`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495713).